# Значение слова "жлоб"

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов, жаргон

Я с детства привыкла употреблять слово ***жлоб*** в значении "неотёсанный нахал", "хам".
Но от других часто слышу это слово в значении "жадина". Есть даже слово ***жлобиться*** — жадничать.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, а какое значение все-таки правильное? Или правильны оба?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По всей видимости, у этого слова есть ряд чисто региональных значений. Например, в Петербурге коренные жители никогда не заменяют этим словом слова "хам" (если судить по речи московских актёров на ТВ, в Москве это почти полные синонимы), применяют его сравнительно редко и почти не образуют от него других слов (напр., не говорят "жлобство"). Обычно придаваемое слову значение: физически сильный и при этом неотёсанный и грубый человек (синоним - скорее, "амбал", чем "хам").

Уже написав это, нашёл совпадающее значение в Энциклопедическом словаре (не во всех словарях так):

жлоб — а; м. Разг. сниж. О физически сильном, но грубом, невоспитанном мужчине.

Answer (score 4):

В словаре ненормативной лексики указываются **два значения  слова *жлоб*:** а) неразвитый, тупой человек («эти два жлоба отметелили не того»); б) скупой, жадный человек.

Впервые слово «жлоб» зафиксировано в 1904 году со значением «мужик, крестьянин»: «выезжает на своей телеге жлоб». Его происхождение – от польского zlob желоб, колода, кормушка для скота. В русское арго слово попало по сходству со словами «жмот, жила».

Казалось бы, разные значения, но образ рисуется один: здоровый, физически крепкий, не слишком умственно развитый, но с крестьянской хваткой, скуповатый, мелочный, ищущий выгоду для себя.

От этого слова образованы производные «жлобяра и жлобский», которые используются в молодежном жаргоне (часто в речи молодых музыкантов):  «Думаешь, он человек? Нет, человечишка! Маленький, подленький, жлобяра, одни словом». «Жлобская свадьба, никакого к нам уважения, даже играть для них не хочется».

Источник: М. Грачев «Русский жаргон. Историко-этимологический словарь».

Answer (score 2):

Академик Д.С. Лихачев считал слово "жлоб" антонимом слова "интеллигент"

Answer (score 2):

Недалекий, примитивный человек. Скуповатый, туповатый; с упрощенным, мещанским восприятием и суждением. Человек с низким культурным уровнем и отсутствующим вкусом, т.е. вульгарный.

Answer (score 1):

Хочу рассказать еще об одном значении слова ЖЛОБ, которое сейчас практически не применяется по причинам, которые станут понятными чуть-чуть позже. Это, по сути, горожанин совсем недавнего поколения. Ну первого, второго... Хотя сейчас это уже и не столь важно. Именно это значение мы встречаем у Андрея Платонова. Посмотрите его "Рассказ не состоящего больше во жлобах" или "Сокровенный человек". Родившись в семье пролетария, Платонов именно это значение ЖЛОБА и знал. Так же, как и я (манией величия не страдаю и в один ряд с Платоновым себя не ставлю!), будучи коренным горожанином черт знает в каком поколении, именно это значение с детства и слышал. Слышал от родителей, родственников, круга знакомых, принадлежащих к реликтовому уже "клану горожан". А детство моё пришлось на период очередной ожлобизации, которая является оборотной стороной урбанизации. Так что термин тогда был очень даже в ходу. Но с развитием этой самой ожлобизации слово как-то потеряло популярность. Да это и понятно. Страну захлестнула волна мигрантов из деревень. Сами себя они так не называли, называть их так в их присутствии было чревато, а место без их присутствия было найти проблематично - куда ни плюнь, попадешь в жлоба. Предприимчивые, бойкие, не отягощенные интеллигентскими соплями и непонятной моралью они буквально смели городской уклад, подстроив его под себя. В городах стали активно гнать самогон, второе рождение получила гармошка, частушки вытеснили городские романсы. Вот что значит массовка! Если раньше деревенские проникали в города "мелкими порциями" и были просто вынуждены подстраиваться под существующий уклад, то при активном заполонении массовка уже заставляла подстраиваться и переделываться под себя. Нечто похожее происходит и сейчас. Новый виток, но на другом уровне. В относительно микромасштабе та же Москва. Как социума ее уже не стало. "Понаехали" и переделали ее под знакомый уклад своих Мухосрансков и Задрючинсков. В макромасштабе происходит переделка страны. Мигранты из ближнего зарубежья не желают приспосабливаться и переделываться под традиционную культуру нового места жительства. Идет переделка под них. Возникают эдакие мутанты социума. Теперь вы понимаете, как дико было горожанам смотреть на вас, когда вы обустраивались в городах? Не могу спорить, может такая интеграция и закономерный процесс. Не знаю. Я просто констатирую факты и привожу еще одно значение слова ЖЛОБ, которое было распространено, но значение которого сейчас почти утеряно, так как тех, кем оно применялось (горожане), пора заносить в Красную книгу. Например:-- А ты знаешь приказ о трудовых армиях? -- спросил комиссар. -- Это чтобы жлобы слесарями сразу стали и заводы пустили? Знаю! А давно ты их ноги вкрутую ставить научил? -- В Реввоенсовете не дураки сидят! -- серьезно выразился комиссар. -- Там взвесили "за" и "против"! -- Это я понимаю, -- согласился Пухов. -- Там -- задумчивые люди, только жлоб механики враз не поймет! -- Ну, а кто ж тогда все чудеса науки и ценности международного империализма произвел? -- заспорил комиссар. -- А ты думал, паровоз жлоб сгондобил? (с) Андрей Платонов "Сокровенный человек".

http://ogmion.ru/p0034.htm

Comment: Боже, словам тесно, а мыслям просторно... Здесь ценятся конкретные ответы на понятные вопросы. А эпосами ни о чем  - извольте на литературные форумы.

Answer (score 0):

Жлоб в сегодняшнем контексте - это человек любого пола, не видящий ничего, кроме себя и своих интересов, и ведущий себя открыто или агрессивно по-хамски по отношению к окружающим.