# Как называется качество человека, который продолжает ездить на ржавом запорожце?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, значение-слов

Как правильно назвать человека или его качество, характерное для следующего примера?

У абстрактного человека (АЧ) есть автомобиль. Плохой, допустим, старый-ржавый запорожец. Этот автомобиль при всей своей никудышности ездит, т.е. свою функцию как автомобиль он выполняет.

Есть абстрактный друг (АД) абстрактного человека, который говорит АЧ:

> - Смени автомобиль, ведь у тебя есть все возможности для этого. Новый будет лучше, комфортнее и презентабильнее.

На что наш герой АЧ отвечает:

> - Зачем мне менять автомобиль? У меня есть запорожец и он свою функцию выполняет. А то, что он не комфортный и выглядит так что дети вокруг плакать начинают, так это не причина менять автомобиль.

Как можно назвать этого АЧ или его качество "нежелания что-либо менять на лучшее"?

P. S. Все совпадения случайны, история выдумана :)

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что  идет не обсуждение языковых проблем, а высказывание мнений на моральную тему. В это случае некоторые пользователи начинают считать свое мнение абсолютно верным  и минусуют  мнения других. Это не сайт для решения проблем этического характера.

Comment: Извольте, Ксения, данный вопрос о названии (слове), которое я ищу для описанного поведения абстрактного человека. Может быть я привел достаточно "горячий" пример, задев тему автомобилей, но так вы вольны заменить слово автомобиль на слово "кроссовок" или "штаны" или любой другой предмет. Смысл поведения не изменится и как я вижу по ответам наиболее емкого слова (названия) для такого поведения пока не нашлось.

Comment: Пример с машиной, конечно, увел в сторону от основной темы. Сейчас я бы назвала такого человека КРАЙНИМ-МИНИМАЛИСТОМ, или минималистом-отшельником. Минимализм как стиль жизни понимается по-разному. Некоторым людям нужен минимум вещей, но при этом вещей качественных. Ваш герой предпочитает минимум затрат на свое физическое существование, также его философия минимализма применима и к общественным отношениям.

Comment: У него нет желания тратить свои энергетические и психические ресурсы на коммуникативные связи, ему безразлично мнение окружающих о нем.  Он строит свою жизнь по собственным понятиям, у него свои интересы и ценности.

Comment: Равиолли , инертный не подходит?

Answer (score 6):

Из словаря Ефремовой:

[**непритяза́тельный**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/196088/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Не предъявляющий высоких требований к кому-либо или к чему-либо; довольствующийся малым.

[**неприхотли́вый**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/196091/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Довольствующийся самым необходимым, крайне скромный в требованиях и потребностях.

[**непритяза́тельность**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/196087/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C)

отвлеч. сущ. по прил. ***непритязательный***

[**неприхотли́вость**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/196090/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#sel=4:1,6:5)

отвлеч. сущ. по прил. ***неприхотливый***

Answer (score 3):

По-моему, вопрос лишь частично касается русского языка, но в большей степени он побуждает нас дать моральную оценку поведению человека в не вполне определенной ситуации. "Нежелание что-либо менять на лучшее" может быть обусловлено совершенно разными причинами, ими могут быть и скупость, и скрытность, и бережливость, и скромность, и аскетизм, и консерватизм, и страх перемен, и многое другое.

Comment: Кто-то назовёт его "глубоким экономом", человеком практичным или "презревшим низменный культ вещей и потребительство", а кто-то - "скупердяем". Это всё субъективные оценки.

Comment: @Ксения, Вам не знакомы люди, которые не расстаются со старыми вещами, как не расстаются со старыми друзьями? Тем более что машина подобна верному коню?  Или просто не любящие никаких изменений вокруг себя? Или считающие время, проведенное в магазине, потраченным зря?

Comment: Да разные есть чудики, да только вопрос-то какой был? Кто не хочет менять плохое (устаревшее) на хорошее (новое), если у него есть такая возможность? Неужели Вы не поменяете старую технику на новую? Например, будете смотреть ламповый телевизор только потому, что он что-то еще показывает. Или будете чинить допотопную стиральную машину, так как не можете с этим "старым другом" расстаться?

Comment: @Ксения, Я — нет, а мои родители, пережившие войну и голод, — да, и они вовсе не были "чудиками", а так были воспитаны. И все деньги отдавали детям, а сами были именно непритяза́тельны. И крошки не выбрасывали не ради экономии, а из уважения к хлебу.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, одним словом тут не получится. Ваше описание не дает исчерпывающей характеристики героя, вопрос в том, насколько искренны его чувства. Может, ему просто лень или денег не хватает. Или боится, что новую машину он разобьет или у него украдут.
На все эти случаи есть разные характеристики персонажа. Это, как было сказано, и *консерватор*, и *непритязательный* и даже в переносном значении - *нестяжатель* (аскет). Поди тут разбери, кто он на самом деле...

Если же он говорит то, что реально думает, то я бы назвал его **конформистом** - в неполитическом значении слова. Человек, который ко всему приспосабливается, не желая что-то менять.

Answer (score 2):

Это *нормальный* человек.

Машина ездит? Ездит. А других требований у владельца нет, поэтому нет и никакого смысла менять машину.

Требования к комфорту, современности и пр. в данном случае - требования окружающих, а не владельца.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что такого человека можно назвать **жлобом.** На форуме есть вопрос на эту тему [Значение слова "жлоб"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/44934/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B6%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B1/44938#44938)

**Цитата из ответа:**

"В словаре ненормативной лексики указываются два значения слова жлоб: а) неразвитый, тупой человек; б) скупой, жадный человек.

Впервые слово «жлоб» зафиксировано в 1904 году со значением «мужик, крестьянин»: «выезжает на своей телеге жлоб». Его происхождение – от польского zlob желоб, колода, кормушка для скота. В русское арго слово попало по сходству со словами «жмот, жила».

Казалось бы, разные значения, но **образ рисуется один**: здоровый, физически крепкий, не слишком умственно развитый, но с крестьянской хваткой, скуповатый, мелочный, **ищущий выгоду для себя"**.

**А сейчас? Сохранилось ли это слово в языке?** Да, им часто пользуются, хотя не всегда ясно, о каких конкретно качествах личности идет речь. Скорее всего, здесь **целый негативный комплекс**.

http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%E6%EB%EE%E1

В том случае, который описывается в вопросе, это человек, которому безразлично, что он живет в обществе:  он считает, что  может заботиться  только о своем комфорте.

Он поступает **согласно своей философии** (может быть, и не совсем ясной, но **это не так важно**) и  действительно во всем ищет **выгоду и удобство только для себя**.

Для такого поведения трудно подобрать слово: может быть, он бережливый,  может быть, непритязательный  или консервативный, а может быть, жадный, скупой и расчетливый.

Но не в этом дело, здесь нужна **обобщенная оценка**, вот и надо подобрать для такой оценки нужное слово.

**Нормальный человек?** Но вот, к примеру, во дворе нашего дома много машин (не каждый может позволить купить себе подземный гараж). Но нет среди них ржавого запорожца, все машины  выглядят очень прилично. Ни одного "нормального" человека не нашлось.

Comment: Удивительно, но ни одно из двух определений слова "жлоб" не подходит к описанию.

Comment: Как уже сказано, слово, судя по его использованию в речи,  имеет неопределенную, комплексную оценку, но в его основе лежит нечто общее, восходящее  еще к началу века. Жлоб мне представляется все тем же крестьянским единоличником, мелочным, расчетливым, прижимистым, который зря копейки не потратит. Но главное - он единоличник, он не привык думать о других, вообще о чем-либо вне своего "хозяйства".

Comment: Сдается мне, вы или ситуацию по-своему поняли или углядели в слове *жлоб* что-то такое другим неведомое. Я допуская, что у жлоба может быть какая-то "философия", но даже если так, то она очень далека от описанного. Из всех значений "жлоба" только одно "жадина" хоть как-то можно привязать к ситуации нежелания тратить деньги, но тут-то мотивы явно другие.

Comment: Я,  кстати, после комментария автора изменила свое мнение и дала там же другой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, это консервативный человек.

Значение слова **консервативный** по Ефремовой:

1. Отстаивающий неизменность чего-л.
2. Проявляющий враждебность по отношению к новому, прогрессивному.

Comment: Оценка "консервативный" чаще употребляется для оценки политических взглядов, жизненной философии человека, но может характеризовать и его отношение к вещам. К примеру, кто-то привык носить классический мужской костюм, но это не значит, что он будет его носить, если он порвется и испачкается. Он просто купит себе новую одежду в том же стиле.

Comment: Ну, если это не подходит, то есть слово ИНЕРТНЫЙ -  это человек, который думает: "мне не нужно ничего менять, у меня и так все нормально", но такие люди ещё и безынициативны, бездеятельны, нерешительны, иногда апатичны.

Answer (score 1):

Есть вполне устоявшийся англицизм на этот случай. Простите, если пропустил выше, каюсь читал «наискосок», треть выпала из поля зрения.
А, да, слово! *Дауншифтер*.

[Этимология несложная.](https://argo.academic.ru/1231/%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80)

> Термин «дауншифтинг» происходит от английского down shift — «движение
>   вниз». Так называют людей, которые сознательно отказываются от
>   солидной должности и высокой зарплаты в пользу… Ну, в общем, чего
>   угодно — семьи, хобби, путешествий, просто лежания на диване. Такие
>   люди были всегда, но сам термин «дауншифтинг» возник только в 1994
>   году.